# Why linear kernel regression is equivalent to plain linear regression?

Tags: linear-regression, kernel

I am trying to understand either intuitively/geometricaly and/or mathematicaly why the followings are equivalent:

- Classic Ordinay Least Squares linear regression
- Linear-kernelized Ordinary Least Squares linear regression

A python example shows that they are numericaly equivalent: I use an OLS regression using only numpy and matrix inversion, and sklearn with classic linear regressor and KernelRidge regressor with 0 regularization. This example show that although the kernel approach uses 100 coefficients, the solution is linear.

```py
%matplotlib qt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels

np.random.seed(0)
n = 100
X_ = np.random.uniform(3, 10, n).reshape(-1, 1)
beta_0 = 2
beta_1 = 2
true_y = beta_1 * X_ + beta_0
noise = np.random.randn(n, 1) * 0.5 # change the scale to reduce/increase noise
y = true_y + noise

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, squeeze=False, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(18, 8))
axes[0, 0].plot(X_, y, "o", label="Input data")
axes[0, 0].plot(X_, true_y, '--', label='True linear relation')
axes[0, 0].set_xlim(0, 11)
axes[0, 0].set_ylim(0, 30)
axes[0, 0].legend()

# f_0 is a column of 1s
# f_1 is the column of x1
X = np.c_[np.ones((n, 1)), X_]

beta_OLS_scratch = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y
lr = LinearRegression(
    fit_intercept=False, # do not fit intercept independantly, since we added the 1 column for this purpose
).fit(X, y)
krr = KernelRidge(
    alpha=0, # no regularization
    kernel="linear",
).fit(X, y)

new_X = np.linspace(0, 15, 50).reshape(-1, 1)
new_X = np.c_[np.ones((50, 1)), new_X]
new_y_OLS_scratch = new_X @ beta_OLS_scratch 
new_y_lr = lr.predict(new_X)
new_y_krr = krr.predict(new_X)
axes[0, 1].plot(X_, y, 'o', label='Input data')
axes[0, 1].plot(new_X[:, 1], new_y_OLS_scratch, '-o', alpha=0.5,  label=r"OLS scratch solution")# $\beta=[" + f'{beta_OLS_scratch.flatten()}'+r"]$")
axes[0, 1].plot(new_X[:, 1], new_y_lr, '-*', alpha=0.5, label=r"sklearn.lr OLS solution")# $\beta=["+f"{lr.coef_.flatten()}" + r"]$")
axes[0, 1].plot(new_X[:, 1], new_y_krr, '-*', alpha=0.5, label=r"sklearn.krr linear kernel")# $\beta=["+f"{lr.coef_.flatten()}" + r"]$")
axes[0, 1].legend()
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: All regressions lead to the same results]

**Why it make sense that they are equivalent:**
Mathematicaly, I feel like since the kernel uses only linear operations, it kinda make sense that we get a linear solution, but this feels not enough justification compared to the fact that it creates a huge dimension space. Also, it kinda make sence since the associated transformation to linear kernel is the identity:
$$K(x,y) = \left< \phi(x),\phi(y)\right> = \phi(x)^T \phi(y) = x^T y$$
since for linear kernel $\phi(x)=x$.

**But also why it doesn't make sense:**
Intuitively, I would've expected that since using a kernel expands the feature space to lots of dimensions (given by the number of inputs in the traning set, here $m'=n=100$ dimensions), the solution (projected back onto the original space) would've been non-linear (and probably expose overfitting). But no, the final solution is perfectly linear AND identical to classic OLS regression.

**My take at prooving this mathematicaly**

Notations:

- $X_{ij}$ row-i, column-j element of input matrix $X$ of shape n by m.
- $i=1...n$, with $n$ the number of rows in the input data matrix
- $j=1...m$, with $m$ the number of columns in the input data matrix
- $j^{'}=1...m'=n$, with $m'$ the number of columns of the linear kernel approach, that is $n$
- $\beta_j$ the regression coefficient of the standard OLS regression, $j=1...m$
- $\beta^{'}_{j^{'}}$ the regression coefficient of the kernel approach, $j^{'}=1...m^{'}=n$

The initial linear regression is:
$$Y_n = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
...\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}_{[n]} = 
X_{[n\times m]}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0\\
...\\
\beta_m
\end{bmatrix}_{[m]}
+ \epsilon_{[n]}$$
$$y_i = \sum_j^m X_{ij}\beta_j + \epsilon_i$$
with solution:
$$\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T y$$

The linear-kernel transformed problem becomes with kernel:
$$K = k_{ij} = X_i \cdot X_j = \sum_k^m X_{ik} X_{jk}$$
we get
$$Y_n = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
...\\
y_n\\
\end{bmatrix}=
K_{[n\times m^{'}=n]} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0\\
...\\
\beta_{m^{'}}\\
\end{bmatrix}_{[m^{'}=n]} + \epsilon^{'}_{[n]}
$$
$$y_i = \sum_{j^{'}}^{m^{'}=n} K_{ij^{‘}} \beta^{'}_{j^{'}} + \epsilon^{'}_{i}$$
$$y_i = \sum_{j^{'}}^{m^{'}=n} \left( \sum_k^m X_{ik}X_{j'k} \right) \beta^{'}_{j^{'}} + \epsilon^{'}_{i}$$
$$y_i = \sum_{j^{'}}^{m^{'}=n} \overrightarrow{X_i} \cdot \overrightarrow{X_{j'}} \beta^{'}_{j^{'}} + \epsilon^{'}_{i}$$
with solution:
$$\beta^{'} = (K^TK)^{—1}K^Ty$$
Since
$$K = (\overrightarrow{X_i}\cdot \overrightarrow{X_j})_{ij} = XX^T$$
$$\beta^{'} = ((XX^T)^TXX^T)^{—1}(XX^T)^Ty \text{(1)}$$

So I guess to show that both approaches are equivalent, I would have to proove that any new dataset $X_{\text{new}}$ would give the new y values, that is:
$$Y_{\text{new}}= X_{\text{new}} \beta= X_{\text{new}} X^T \beta^{'} $$
Am I right ? is this possible ?

**Conclusion**
Although some arguments can be accounted for the fact that linear regression and linear-kernel regression lead to the same solution, I cannot understand why using a high-dimension space still gives back a linear solution once projected back onto the low-dimension space. Also, I cannot proove that both approaches are equivalent mathematicaly, although it seems possible.

**[EDIT]** With [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813060/linear-regression-proving-that-linear-regression-is-linear-invariant), I ended up showing exactly the mathematical proof I was looking for:
Continuing from $\text{(1)}$ and using $(XX^T)^T=X^{TT}X^T=XX^T$:
$$\beta^{'} = ((XX^T)^TXX^T)^{—1}(XX^T)^Ty \text{(1)}$$
$$\beta^{'} = (XX^TXX^T)^{—1}XX^Ty$$
$$\beta^{'} = X^{-T}(X^TX)^{-1}X^{—1}XX^Ty$$
$$\beta^{'} = X^{-T}(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$
so
$$X_{\text{new}} X^T \beta^{'} = X_{\text{new}} X^T X^{-T}(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = X_{\text{new}} (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = X_{\text{new}} \beta $$
I am still looking for a geometric/intuitive proof.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might or might not be an intuition, but the simplest explanation that I can come up with is the following.

take a linear model with $w$ as weights, we can prove that
$$
w = \sum_i \alpha_i x_i
$$

that is, the weights must be a linear combination of the training set.

Then, we can simply rewrite the linear model loss function with this new formalization:
$$
L(\theta) = \sum_j(w^Tx_j- y_j)^2 = \sum_j \left[(\sum_i \alpha_i x_i)x_j - y_i\right]^2
$$

And now you can clearly see that this is literally kernel regression with linear kernel